# PartCover with msTest in Cruise control .net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, mstest, partcover

Can anybody tell me how to use partcover in Cruise control .net  along with mstest,

I have done that but i am getting an error

```
errorMSB3073: The command "C:\Program Files\PartCover\PartCover .NET 4.0\PartCover.exe --target=${nunitExePath} --target-work-dir=D:\Demo_Project\ --target-args=D:\DEMO\TestProject\bin\Debug\TestProject.dll --include=[LaTrompa]* --output=${partCoverReportPath}\${projectTests}-Results.xml" exited with code 9009.
```

I have used following command in msbuild

```
<PropertyGroup>
<partCoverReportPath>D:\BuildReports\PartCover\</partCoverReportPath>
<nunitExePath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe</nunitExePath>
```

-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following command

```
C:\Program Files\PartCover\PartCover .NET 4.0\PartCover.exe" --target "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" --include [TestProjectName]* --include [More if u have]* --target-args "/noisolation /testcontainer:path\TestProjectName.dll" --target-work-dir "Working dir of project" --output "output pathr\partcover.xml
```